# Directory structure of NodeJS/ExpressJS/HandlebarsJS fullstack project

Tags: node.js, express, handlebars.js, directory-structure

I know this type of questions are borderline for SO due to the subjectiveness of the answers, but is there any standard or best practise for the directory structure of NodeJS/ExpressJS/HandlebarsJS fullstack projects?

I have several of these projects and in each of them I still struggle on what should be the best approach:

- do you split by `client/` and `server/`?
- Do you have two `node_modules/` directories and two respective `package.json`, one for client and other for server?
- If you split them, where do you put the `templates/` and `views/` used by the server to dynamically generate html code to the client?

Comment: I wouldn't call it "borderline", it's quite clearly a question that will result in opinion-based answers.

Comment: @robertklep that's why I asked if "there is any standard or best practise". But I see there isn't.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As I see it you want explanation for a monorepo structure.

#### About the questions:

**#1**

> Do you split by `client/` and `server/` ?

If the `/server` provides HTML and other static content to the `/client` in your full stack project, it makes more sense to do it differently. For example like this:

[image]

Think of the `/src` folder as the `/server` folder, and `/public` as `/client`.

**#2**

> Do you have two `node_modules/` directories and two respective
> `package.json`, one for client and other for server?

We are working in a monorepo and all our modules are nested. Due to our project structure, the front-end is not free anyway, so there is no need for a separate `node_modules` and `package.json`.

**#3**

> If you split them, where do you put the `templates/` and `views/` used by the
> server to generate html code to the client?

We did not separate them. So all the workers goes to `/src`. Only the static part goes into `/public`.

---

#### What is the problem, and what is going on?

**- Monorepo:** For example we have a very busy social media application. Users upload millions of photos every day. In order to deliver this seamlessly, we need to scale up our servers. We chose [horizontal scaling](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11715598/11586487) as the solution. But what is the problem? Problem: We wanted to scale up only the photo serving/uploading part, but due to our structure we had to scale everything at additional expense. So let's say there were no new members coming to our application, so that part was comfortable, but we scaled it up for no reason.

**- Node/Express to serve static files:** is just a bad idea. You should not use your application server (especially express) to serve static content like html, css, js and other libraries. The best way to serve them is via a content distribution netwrok (CDN). Or, serve then from your web server (nginx or apache).

**- Unnecessary confusion:** As you can see, everything is very complicated, and the modules are interconnected. Testing, sharing, working with the team are all very difficult. If we want to make a small change in our structure in the future, it may take a lot of effort.

---

#### How could it be better?

First you have to completely separate the frontend and the backend. You can use Express just as an API server. And you can use frameworks like React, VueJs, Angular for frontend. It doesn't matter, it can be plain JS/CSS/HTML too. And you can use servers like Nginx or Apache to serve them.

Try to adapt your projects to microservices architecture. Microservices architecture will both reduce complexity and provide convenience for you in any future structure changes. And it is easy to test. On this road, [Docker](https://www.docker.com/) can be a very good friend to you.

If you still want to stay in the monorepo architecture after everything, you can stay using the way I mentioned in About the questions section, there is no problem with it and in addition, it is useful to read [this blog](https://blog.logrocket.com/organizing-express-js-project-structure-better-productivity/).

---

### Extra

> so in `/public` you just put static content? Why `views/` go the `/src` if it is client related?

Think like there are three parts in our monorepo approach:

1. static
2. mix of static and dynamic
3. dynamic.

**1. Static:** for example, when we say `example.com/css/style.css` it should serve us directly our css file (the same one we have locally). Or when we right click on any photo on the website and open image in a new tab, it should redirect you to an address like `example.com/img/the_image.jpeg`. Everything is ready and only needs to be served. This is what we call "static" here. And only those go to `/public`.

**2. Mix of static and dynamic:** Our code takes the data, fill in the necessary places, and presents the page filled with the data to the users. And all this happens in the `/views` folder. As you can see, there is a compile process here, the result is not ready at first. So it cannot be called "static".

If frontend and backend were separate. Our frontend javascript code would make a fetch call to our backend server, it would get the necessary data and fill on its own. And all this would happen on the browser independent from the server. (This was an example of pure client side rendering. Have a look [SSR vs CSR](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27291188/11586487) )

*(There are so many options and different methods for this job (using ejs, pug, handlebars or react, vue, angular) and if we go any further this will be an opinion-based answer. Or it's already an opinion-based, it will be even more)*

**3. Dynamic:** Our regular backend code.

Comment: so in `/public` you just put static content? Why `views/` go the `/src` if it is client related? What do you think about [this](https://simonplend.com/what-is-a-good-directory-structure-for-a-monorepo-with-a-node-js-back-end-and-react-front-end/) approach?

Comment: I added the section called "Extra" to answer first part of your question.  For the second part, This is one of the options. The folder structure is actually shaped according to what you want to do. There are general concepts, all structures other than those concepts are different. And personally, it won't do you any good to take my opinion.

Comment: Interesting, thus in the Extra section you divide the code in three concepts, whereas previously you divided in `src/` and `public/`. Yes, I need monorepo, because my projects are open source and with monorepo it's easy to replicate (clone) everything at once.

Comment: It's okay, you just misunderstood me. I said "**Think** like there are three parts in our monorepo approach" for explanation of "static" and "dynamic" concepts for the specific and known structure.   In general, you can use any structure you want. But if you just need sample. You can take a look at other open source projects that already exist.

Comment: thus it would be structurally ok to divide the monorepo project into `public/`, `views/` and `dynamic/`?

Comment: You can do what ever you want. And I think the topic seems to be getting too long. I explained and answered the original question in the necessary form above.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248356/discussion-between-sh2a-and-joao-pimentel-ferreira).